# Find the closed form of $u_{n+1}=a_nu_n+b_n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, telescopic-series

**Note**
Since a more general answer has been given to the initial problem by 
**@Renji Rodrigo,** 
**I decided to improve the post in other to avoid future duplicate regarding such question like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630199/solving-a-n1-3a-n2n?noredirect=1&lq=1)**

> **Question** what is the closed form of the sequence $(a_n)_n$ with following recursive relation? 
>   $$\color{blue}{u_{n+1}=a_nu_n+b_n~~~\text{where $a_1$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are given.}}$$

**Initial question**

> **The initial question was just the particular case of the aforementioned general question**. Namely 
>   Let $a_2 = 2$ and $b_2= -\frac{1}{2}$ and
>   consider 
>   $$a_{n+1} =a_n\frac{n-1}{n+1}+\frac{2}{n+1}~~~and~~~~b_{n+1} =b_n\frac{n-1}{n+1}~~n\ge 2$$
>   I would like to fine the closed form of $a_n$ and $b_n$

So far By telescopic product I was able to get the formula for $b_n$, as follows

$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_2}=\prod^{n}_{k=2}\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}=\prod^{n}_{k=2}\frac{k-1}{k+1}=\prod^{n}_{k=2}\frac{k-1}{k}\prod^{n}_{k=2}\frac{k}{k+1} =\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$$
Hence $$b_{n+1}=- \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

> Now I don't know which trick I should use here in other to come up with the closed form of $a_n$ Can someone provide some hint or an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show you a more general way to find solutions, you can apply that method later to your problem ( and others of the same type)

> **Theorem(Solution of the recurrence)**
>   Given sequences $g(n) \neq 0$ and $b(n)$, we have that $f(n)$
>   the solution of the recurrence
>   $$f(n+1)=g(n).f(n)+b(n)$$
>   is given by
>   $$f(n)= \bigg(\sum^{n-1}_{p=1}\frac{b(p)}{\prod\limits^{p}_{k=1}g(k)}+f(1) \bigg)\prod^{n-1}_{k=1}g(k). $$

**Moreover,:**  in the same way we can show
$$ f(n)= h(c)\prod^{n-1}_{k=a}g(k) + \prod^{n-1}_{k=a}g(k)\bigg(\sum^{n-1}_{p=c}\frac{b(p)}{\prod\limits^{p}_{k=a}g(k)} \bigg)$$
**Notation:** $\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$

**Proof\deduction**

Let $h(n)$ be define by $$h(n)=\frac{f(n)}{\prod\limits^{n-1}_{k=a}g(k)},$$ so that,
$$f(n)=h(n)\prod^{n-1}_{k=a}g(k) ~~~~and~~~~f(n+1)=h(n+1)\prod^{n}_{k=a}g(k)  $$
substitute tha term on the recurrence,
$$h(n+1)\prod^{n}_{k=1}g(k)=h(n)g(n)\prod^{n-1}_{k=1}g(k)+b(n)=h(n)\prod^{n}_{k=1}g(k)+b(n) $$
then
$$ h(n+1)\prod^{n}_{k=1}g(k)-h(n)\prod^{n}_{k=1}g(k)= b(n)$$
$$\Delta h(n)\prod^{n}_{k=1}g(k)=b(n)$$
$$\Delta h(n)=\frac{b(n)}{\prod\limits^{n}_{k=1}g(k)} $$
apply the sum $\sum\limits^{n-1}_{p=1}$ on both sides, it's telescopic
$$\sum^{n-1}_{p=1}\Delta h(p)=h(n)-h(1)=\sum^{n-1}_{p=1}\frac{b(p)}{\prod\limits^{p}_{k=1}g(k)}, $$
so
$$h(n)=\sum^{n-1}_{p=1}\frac{b(p)}{\prod\limits^{p}_{k=1}g(k)}+h(1) $$
then
$$f(n)= \prod^{n-1}_{k=1}g(k)\bigg(\sum^{n-1}_{p=1}\frac{b(p)}{\prod\limits^{p}_{k=1}g(k)}+h(1) \bigg). $$

Obs: $h(1)=f(1)$

Answer (score 1):

Now, let $a_n=b_n+1$ for some sequence $b$.

Thus, $$b_{n+1}=(b_n+1)\frac{n-1}{n+1}+\frac{2}{n+1}$$ or 
$$b_{n+1}+1=\frac{n-1}{n+1}b_n+\frac{n-1}{n+1}+\frac{2}{n+1}$$ or
$$b_{n+1}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}b_n$$ and use your work.

Comment: Sorry but I dont get the point\

Comment: I added something. See now.

Comment: My point is the constant 1. where does that come from?

Comment: Because $\frac{n-1}{n+1}+\frac{2}{n+1}=1$.

Comment: perfect it works although  I dont know how you came up with that

Comment: Don't know. I just saw it.

Comment: Ok what if the there were 3 instead of 2? I mean in  the term $\frac{2}{n+1}$

Comment: I think it would be hard already.

Comment: There should be some logic behind this trick I am just trying to guess but thank

Answer (score 0):

The closed form is $a_n=\begin{cases}a\in\mathbb{R},&n=1\\1,&n\geq2\end{cases}$

It can be verified by substituting the first few $n$'s in the formula (also very easy to show by induction).